# Set up a DataFrame index to be DateTime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a `pd.DataFrame` which has `datetime64` type of index. I'd like to concatenate a `pd.Series` column to it and map it to the index.

However, my `pd.Series` has an `object` type of dates, while my `pd.DataFrame` has a `datetime64` type of dates.

I tried converting the `pd.Series` index to `datetime` like so.

This is how the `pd.Series` looks like :

```py
west_index[1:5]
Out[40]: 
                 WEST
Exchange Date        
2005-01-05    -0.7466
2005-01-06        NaN
2005-01-07     0.3401
2005-01-10    -0.0688
```

I did:

```py
a = [datetime.strptime(_, '%Y-%m-%d') for _ in west_index.index]
west_index.set_index(a, inplace=True)
```

When I try to concatenate to my main `pd.DataFrame`, which looks like this:

```py
log_r[500:505]
Out[42]: 
                BELEX15       BET       BUX  ...    STOXX50     WIG20  
Exchange Date                                ...                           
2006-12-08     0.131916  1.717272 -0.983922  ...   0.090416 -0.436533   
2006-12-11     0.191401 -0.645286  1.158256  ...   0.576408 -0.086710   
2006-12-12    -0.190785 -0.764530  0.753001  ...   0.396716 -0.684809   
2006-12-13    -0.521898  0.726442 -1.459122  ...   0.629700  0.202408   
2006-12-14     0.877326 -0.707257  1.099898  ...   0.718143  0.722291
```

```py
log_r = pd.concat([log_r,west_index], axis=1)
```

I get an error

> KeyError: datetime.datetime(2005, 1, 4, 0, 0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think better is convert `log_r.index` or `west_index.index` to datetimes for datetimes in both indexes by [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
#check it
print (west_index.index.dtype)
print (log_r.index.dtype)

west_index.index = pd.to_datetime(west_index.index)
log_r.index = pd.to_datetime(log_r.index)
log_r = pd.concat([log_r, west_index], axis=1)
```